# Pressing Ctrl Alt 0 is not working for me

Tags: interface

I'm learning through [Blender Guru's videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTxBrjN1ugA&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&index=7) and he said press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and it's not working for me. And even when he sculpted the donut I did not quite understand how to do it. Anyone know? Maybe there is another way?

Comment: Have you pressed Ctrl + Alt + Numpad 0 to set the camera? You need a keyboard with a number pad for this. It's *not* the 0 on the upper key row. If you don't have a number pad you can press F3 to search for the command 'align active camera to view'. To help you with the sculpting you need to be more specific. What exactly did you not understand? What exactly does not work? What did you do and where was there a problem?

Comment: I did not understand how to make the socket I tried to click on the place where I want to sculpt but it did not work for me.
Thanks for the help! It really helped me.❤

Comment: It's hard to tell why it doesn't work for you. Do you want to add a screenshot to your question? You can also share your blend file here (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). For sculpting, you need to be in Sculpt Mode, have the correct object selected, have enough geometry (check it in wire mode), use the right brush and have brush strength set to a good value, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not answer. I got it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>. It's important to use the <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> not the normal <kbd>0</kbd> on the upper key row.

If you don't have a number pad you can press <kbd>F3</kbd> to open a search box (or <kbd>Space</kbd> - depends on preferences that you have set). There, search for the command '*align active camera to view*'. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> is the shortcut for it and listed there, too.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to ensure that there is an active camera object in the scene before you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> doesn't work, is probably because "Emulate 3 Button Mouse" has been enabled in the preferences.

The easiest way around this is to change the keybinding for this action:

1. Press <kbd>F3</kbd>
2. In the search box that comes up, search for "align active camera to view"
3. Right-click on that option and choose "change shortcut"
4. It will then let you press the new key combination you want to use
5. It will accept your new key binding, even though there is no visual confirmation of that

If you wanted to manually choose this option, it can be found in the menus by going to *View > Align View > Align Active Camera to View*

Answer (score 0):

I also don't have a numpad on my keyboard, so I simply changed the hotkey to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> from edit\preferences.

Just search for "Align Camera".