# Camera affected to my view

Tags: 3d-view, camera, pie-menu

I want to bring the camera to my view, and it dont work.

I saw a lot of answers saying that Ctrl + Alt + Numpad 0 was working, but when I do this it open this Pie menu.

I know that I have enabled it myself, but I dont remember how to disable it lmao...

Can someone tell me the shortkey or something to get rid of this Pie menu ?

Thanks a lot ! Sorry for taking your time :) [image]

Comment: For an alternative method see the answer in this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211293/pressing-ctrl-alt-0-is-not-working-for-me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the shortcut, but is this what you meant?
[image]

Comment: Yes, it could !! Where did you find it ?

Comment: When you're in the viewport, and press "N" key, you'll get these menu
In that goto View--> Camera to view

Comment: It worked ! Thank you a lot <3

Comment: @Wide Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).